# WordPress database error: [Column count doesn't match value count at row 1]

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have a table that looks like this. They all have default 0 value for some reason:

[image]

In wordpress I'm inserting new value of score into a table like so:

```
$scoree = $_POST['whatever'];
global $wpdb;
$table = 'username';
$save = $wpdb->insert($table, $scoree);
wp_send_json(['save' => $save, '$_POST' => $_POST ]);
}
```

But this gives me an error when alerting AJAX response in javascript file:

> Got this from the server: **WordPress database error:** [Column count doesn't match value count at row 1]
> ``` INSERT INTO username (``) VALUES () ```
>
> {"save":false,"$_POST":{"action":"my_action","whatever":"9"}}

My AJAX in JS file:

```
var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'whatever' : user1.currentScore
      }
      jQuery.post(my_ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    }
```

Any ideas why is this hapenning?

Comment: wpdb::insert says it should be a key pair, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/ it says it right there, just follow the format `array(key => pair, another key => another pair)`

Comment: What is a key? There is only $scoree and thats it. I haveno key value pairs

Comment: @Ghost Okay, I understood what you said and fixed it. Working now. But I'm still having 0 value to score column by default, and when I save a new one, each username has two values, the 0 default one and a new one just added. How can I fix this? I don't need that 0 by default, just one value newly added

Comment: just debug whatever the value you're getting. if the insertion is now working, then examine the origin of the value, track it from the start until it reaches in the actual insertion code, use `console.log`, `echo`, `var_dump` accordingly.
`array('name' => 'stan lee', 'score' => $score variable name)` like so